# How to set google maps marker with database value

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am new to google maps api. I create a maps with hardcore values as markers. But I want to create my markers with the values came from database. Here is my code

```
 function initialize() {

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            streetViewControl: false
        });

        var markers = [             // Here I set the hard core values for my markers.
            { lat: 22.64201389, lng: 88.43034722, name: "Airport" },
            { lat: 22.60944444, lng: 88.42694444, name: "Baguihati" },
            { lat: 22.53604167, lng: 88.36083333, name: "Ballygunge Phari" },
            { lat: 22.49895833, lng: 88.31902778, name: "Behala" },
            { lat: 22.65743056, lng: 88.36409722, name: "Dakshineshwar" },
            { lat: 22.62013889, lng: 88.39215278 , name: "Dum-Dum Station." },
            { lat: 22.52111111, lng: 88.36479167, name: "Gariahat" },
            { lat: 22.58763889, lng: 88.34027778, name: "Howrah" },
            { lat: 22.59131944, lng: 88.43291667, name: "Karunamayee East" },
            { lat: 22.52131944, lng: 88.38201389, name: "Kasba Bosepukur" },
            { lat: 22.60256944 , lng: 88.40166667 , name: "Lake Town" },
            { lat: 22.68993056, lng: 88.47569444, name: "Madhyam Gram_East" },
            { lat: 22.50875 , lng: 88.33284722 , name: " New Alipur" },
            { lat: 22.54409722 , lng: 88.36743056, name: "Park circus" },
        ];

        for (index in markers) addMarker(markers[index]);
        function addMarker(data) {
            new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng),
                map: map,
                title: data.name
            });

        }

        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        for (index in markers) {
            var data = markers[index];
            bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng));
        }
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

Please help me to set the database values in the maker.. The values will be comes from servlet.

Comment: do you have latitude, longitude saved in your db ?

Comment: Java and JavaScript are 2 completely different languages!

Comment: I don't know but I want to go to Ballygunge Phari. That's the best place name ever.

Answer (score 3):

You can write a PHP (or whatever the language you use) page which contacts with the database and return the details in it as JSON Array.So that you can easily call it via ajax and retrieve the values you need.If you are using servlets [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/downloads/list) library will be useful when converting objects to JSON. However you should have a database table which contains the latitude,longitude and the name.

maybe this code will help you,write this inside doGet() or doPost() in your servlet

```
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            java.sql.Connection con = new DBConn().getConnection(); //establish the database connection you use

           String getquery = "SELECT * from markers";

            ResultSet res = DBHandle.getData(con, getquery); 
            ArrayList<Marker> markerList;
            markerList = new ArrayList<Marker>();

            while (res.next()) {

              Marker marker=new Marker(); //model class with attributes latitude,longitude and name along with their getters and setters
              marker.setLatitude(res.getString("latitude"));
              marker.setLongitude(res.getString("longitude"));
              marker.setName(res.getString("name"));
              markerList.add(marker);

            }
            String JsonString = gson.toJson(markerList, ArrayList.class);
            out.print(JsonString);
```

And [this](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) would help you when retrieving it in javascript.I prefer using jquery for that.

You can try this code to retrieve it via jquery

```
 $.getJSON("url_with_json_here", function(data){
   for (var i=0, len=data.length; i < len; i++) {
     data[i].latitude;
    console.log(data[i].name);
    console.log(data[i].longitude);
    console.log(data[i].latitude); 
    }
});
```

Comment: String JsonString = gson.toJson(markerList, ArrayList.class);
            out.print(JsonString);                                   This return a json object. now How can read the json and put the value in map???